# Why Not Use CSS Check Boxes as Toggle Buttons

Tags: css, toggle

I'm wondering why I don't see this technique used more often.

A lot of toggle buttons use JavaScript or jQuery to create a toggling function.

Why couldn't you just use a checkbox input and style the label with CSS? Furthermore you could put anything you like after the label and put an absolute position on it wrapped in a relative positioned `input` and style it using `~`

http://jsfiddle.net/j63uk/

```
<input id="button" type="checkbox">
<label for="button">button</label>
</input>

input {
display: none;
}
label {
padding:20px;
position: relative;
background:green;
display: inline-block;
}
label:hover {
  background:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
background:yellow;
}
```

Perhaps the ability to click on anything else on the page and disable the toggle with JavaScript is the main benefit?

Comment: This is perfectly possible, yes. Do you see toggle buttons often, though? Most ones I notice use this technique. (For something expanding, check out the `<details>` element.)

Comment: Really? I hardly ever see buttons like this, unless they are clearly meant to be checkboxes, rather than actual buttons

Comment: An input must not have an end tag. A label wraps an input or the label and input are sibling with a for attribute and id, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This question might be more applicable to [UX Stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). Toggle buttons are often a styled version of radio buttons. Radio buttons are generally applicable in cases where it is important for the user to know the alternative choices (e.g. what class of ticket they want to buy from an airline). Checkboxes are applicable when the user can select multiple options at the same time but it is still important for the user to know the different options offered to them (e.g. Select all of the following that apply...). Using a checkbox for toggling a single choice is a visually similar but less accessible way of implementing styled radio buttons because the code can not as easily be understood by machines (page parsers, search engines, etc) and screen readers. Essentially, radio buttons are a more semantically correct way of styling a toggle and they can be styling to look like a toggle, just like checkboxes could too.

Thus, I don't think it's a matter of which is easier for javascript implementation - it's a question of which gives you the best, most maintainable and semantic code that is accessible for (understanded by) machines and humans alike.

As you mentioned, you could place something after the checkbox or radio and style it using a CSS sibling selector. But even more interestingly, you don't have to duplicate labels or add extra HTML to do this because you could add the CSS rule `direction: rlt;` on the parent element to render elements from the right hand side (therefore, you can visually place the label to the left of the input but still target it with `.checkbox:checked ~ .label` or something similar. Thus, you further increase the usability of your app and maintain the styling advantages of a toggle-like button.

To your point on clicking anywhere on the page to disable the toggle, this can be emulated using a label with a for attribute placed elsewhere on the page. For example:

```
<label for="the_toggle">Click me</label>
// Some random code... blah blah blah...
<input type="checkbox" id="the_toggle">
```

You can use jQuery to toggle radios, checkboxes, etc, too. It's worth noting that the :checked selector is [not supported in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) but it can be enabled using [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/).

**Further Reading:**

- [Radios vs Selects](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/456/when-should-i-use-a-select-box-instead-of-radio-buttons)
- [Styling semantic toggle](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-javascript-free-radio-toggle-in-css3--webdesign-7690)